# What node implementations and mining pools relay and process 'non-standard' scripts?

Tags: script, nodes, non-standard-transaction, relay, transaction-propagation

Which Bitcoin node implementations, if any, currently relay valid transactions that use so-called 'non-standard' scripts? What proportion of the network is made up of these implementations? What proportion of the network's hashing power will include transactions with valid but 'non-standard' scripts in their blocks?

To clarify the term 'non-standard', I'm referring to the function [`IsStandard()`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script.cpp#L1414), and the following [comment on the Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Scripts):

> non-standard scripts are accepted if they are in a block, but nodes will not relay them.

Comment: If non-standard scripts were included in blocks that don't validate with standard nodes you wouldn't be mining Bitcoin anymore, but a fork from Bitcoin that no Bitcoin miner will accept and mine on top of.

Comment: @JacobTorba I'm only talking about valid scripts that _do_ validate with normal nodes. The question is about what implementations _relay_ non-standard scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There is [old] bitcoin version by Lukejr
http://eligius.st/~luke-jr/programs/bitcoin/files/bitcoin-qt/next/test/20130721/
It accepts and relays non-standard transactions running with commandline option "-acceptnonstdtxn"

It is very unstable program, use it with separate database and empty wallet.dat
But it definetely works.

There is at least one pool, which accepts non-standard transactions
It is eligius.st
Its public IP-address is 192.3.11.20
Just add option "connect=192.3.11.20" in your conf file or commandline param and you are a part of "non-standard relaying network"

for more information refer to
https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=260749

Comment: yesterday i've sent tx with non-standard input script https://blockchain.info/ru/tx/6cbca41fcb4d3fdbc900be4a1e7225cfbf929cae61686e0fa42a9ed521648894 and my transacton was successfully included into the next Eligius block #300598

Comment: As of May 2015 the only Eligius node IP I can find that's accepting connections is 68.168.105.168.

Answer (score 0):

0.8.6 still relays transactions with malleable signatures. This fix has been implemented in 0.9.x. However, only a very few percentage actually runs 0.9.x because it's not yet officially released. It's still a release candidate (RC), i.e. feature-complete but not widely tested yet.

Comment: I don't think the question is about malleable signatures but about nonstandard scripts.