# OP_RETURN transaction doesn't go to the blockchain

Tags: bitcoind

I created transaction with OP_RETURN adding some information. Even though transaction hash created successfully, the transaction doesn't go to blockchain properly. Could you please help me to do this transaction properly?

"scriptPubKey":

{

"asm": "OP_RETURN 726173656c6140676d61696c2e636f6d7e39383732363733383834",

"hex": "6a1b726173656c6140676d61696c2e636f6d7e39383732363733383834",

"type": "nonstandard"

}

Answer (score 1):

Can you give the full transaction, and decode it?

The default client nodes will not broadcast your transaction because it is not standard. That may be the problem. If it is mined into a block, however, they would not refuse that block just because it had non-standard transactions, because the transaction would be **valid** even though it might not be **standard**. For more on this, you may find the below questions helpful.

- [Which scripts are currently considered standard and therefore actually propagated?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21123/which-scripts-are-currently-considered-standard-and-therefore-actually-propagate).
- [What node implementations and mining pools relay and process 'non-standard' scripts?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23435/what-node-implementations-and-mining-pools-relay-and-process-non-standard-scri).

That might not even be the problem, though. It could be signed incorrectly. You should make sure that the OP_RETURN output was included before the transaction was signed. You can verify that the signature of the transaction is valid using the code in this question: [How to verify ECDSA of a sample litecoin tx using pycoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32194/how-to-verify-ecdsa-of-a-sample-litecoin-tx-using-pycoin/32217#32217).