# How to broadcast a non standard transaction?

Tags: transactions

How can i broadcast a non standard transaction?

I tried using the core client, coinb, blockchain.info, luke-jr's test release as well as pushing it to eligius but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What node implementations and mining pools relay and process 'non-standard' scripts?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23435/what-node-implementations-and-mining-pools-relay-and-process-non-standard-scri)

Comment: The provided information is somehow insufficient, cause we don't see, what happens in your environment or what actions have been taken so far. To raise a good question, which increases the probability for a good answer, see here:
Have a look at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  Questions which come to my mind: What do you mean by non-standard? Could you provide your example? Are you sure it is syntactically correct? Have you checked on testnet ot regtest before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't - there are likely to few nodes on the network that will forward it far enough to reach a miner.

What you can do is find a miner yourself, contact them, and see what mechanism they offer to include your transaction (perhaps for a fee). In this case, the transaction will not propagate through the network directly; only as part of the block after mining.

Comment: I think F2pool will do it but i need a referral code. Do you have one or know how to get one?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm just trying to point out that if you don't use standard transactions, you're generally on your own and will need help from a miner.